# Why the moment arms in x-direction are considered as -x?

Tags: aerodynamics

[image]

Thanks for anyone reading this question. I am able to understand the signs of the forces, but I could not understand why a negative sign is added to the moment arm in x-direction (please check the last line in the picture).
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your drawing, force is defined positive when upwards. By convention, pitching moment is defined positive in aircraft nose up direction. Origin of the moment is the wing leading edge, so a positive force yields a nose down moment which is negative.

Horizontal forces result in a nose up moment when above the origin, and nose down when below the origin.

That is assuming:

- Positive is up, for force and position.
- Positive is aft, for both force and position.
- Positive is nose up, for moments.

That is the sign convention for which the equation in the book holds. The book should state the sign convention it is using, perhaps you can post that as well.

Comment: How about in y direction, how could the force in y direction create any moment?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to dA: because it is lower or higher than the point of origin.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, technically the equation should have only plus signs, and the value of X would be negative. Also, the value of Y for the lower side forces should be negative while it is positive for the upper side forces. The author selected to subtract the lift force terms while he added both drag force terms even when one of them has a negative lever arm. This is sloppy.

The reference point of the moment is the leading edge, so all lift forces N act at a point behind this reference point. Positive is up and to the right, so a positive moment is trailing edge down. A positive lift force behind the reference point produces a negative moment, so to achieve a positive number the lever arm has to be negative.

In mathematical terms: Positive x is backwards, but you need to go forward in X to move from the force to the reference point. Hence a negative x. But there should not be a minus sign for the variable in the equation.

Comment: So the main reason for the negative sign is due the different direction for a "positive force" and a "positive moment" right?

Comment: @HarryYang: Positive X is backwards, but you need to go forward in x to get from the force to the reference point. Hence a negative x.

Comment: sorry for so many questions from a high school kid... That makes sense, but what about in y direction, the axial forces A for the upper surface, positive Y is upwards, but to get to the reference point you need to go downwards, in this logic, shouldn't the moment arm of y be negative as well?

Comment: @HarryYang: You are right, technically the equation should have only plus signs, and the value of X would be negative. Also, the value of Y for the lower side forces should be negative while it is positive for the upper side forces. The author selected to subtract the lift force terms while he added both drag force terms even when one of them has a negative lever arm. This is sloppy.

Comment: @HarryYang No need to worry about being a high school kid with many questions. I'd have been quite happy to have had my sons be so interested in things aeronautical.

Comment: why would the value of x be negative?

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion stems from an incomplete understanding of reference systems on an aircraft.
The forces and moments are arranged according to the right hand system.
A way to determine what direction the moments point is to use the your right and make a fist. Then point out your thumb. As in the image below:

[image]

[Source](http://adaptivemap.ma.psu.edu/websites/moments/moments/moments.html)

If you put your thumb on the positive direction (so let's say +X force), your fingers curl in the direction of the positive moment (thus in the direction of the arrow that says 'L').

Similarly for your question, we are talking about pitching moments (rotation around the Y-axis), so we have to point are thumb in the positive Y direction. Our fingers then curl with the clock (as seen from the Y-axis). 
The N force is in the opposite direction, making for the - sign.

[image]

[Source](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.control.20120206.06.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an aviation engineer, but a physicist, and see it like this:
There is a pressure $p$ acting perpendicular onto the airfoil, and $\tau$, which seems to be drag, acting parallel to the airfoil to the trailing edge.

Right?

If this is so, one can express the horizontal force $dA$ and vertical force $dN$ on the upper side as:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
p_x&=&-p\sin\theta\\
p_y&=&-p\cos\theta\\
\tau_x&=&\tau\cos\theta\\
\tau_y&=&-\tau\sin\theta\\
\hline
dN&=&p_y+\tau_y=-p\sin\theta-\tau\sin\theta\\
dA&=&p_x+\tau_x=-p\cos\theta+\tau\cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}
$$

[image]

**Note:** The direction of $dN$ is upwards, and that of $dA$ is to the right. The value of this expressions can be negative, making them effectively pointing into the other direction. But we don't have to care about this, math does for us.

Now, in physics, a momentum trying to rotate something counter-clockwise is positive, and a momentum trying to rotate clockwise is negative. But it seems in aviation a moment trying to lift the nose is positive, which in this case means that clockwise rotation is positive. Then, one gets:

An upwards pointing $dN$ tries to turn the wing counter-clockwise, and must give a negative momentum, i.e. $\int -x\cdot dN$. And $dA$ tries to turn the wing clockwise, and gives a positive momentum $\int +y\cdot dA$.

(Please excuse that I'm a bit sloppy about that infinitesimal stuff)

Comment: _Now, in physics, a momentum trying to rotate something counter-clockwise is positive_ Does that depend on which side the pilot stands when he looks at the aircraft? Makes my head spin.

Comment: @Koyovis: Yes, this is called 'parity'. If you are standing left of an aircraft, a clockwise rotation means "nose up". If vou are standing right of an aircraft, "nose up" is counter-clockwise. Sounds weird, but if you think about, it is logical.

Comment: Not for the pilot who sits in the middle.

Comment: @Koyovis: think about the passenger sitting between the wings ;-). However, the rule still applies. Look out of the right and the left window when the AC rotates - how does the horizon move?

Comment: @sweber: I read your answer for several times but I could not see why you say dN is pointing upwards, isn't it in the diagram pointing downward?

Comment: @HarryYang: That's exactly the reason for this question. A vector (0;1) points upwards and would try to rotate ccw. Thus, we have to multiply with -x. But our vector is dN*(0, 1), and because dN<0, it finally points downwards. Another way to see it: The force acts downwards with an absolute value of |dN|, and could then just be multiplied with +x to get the correct result. MAybe, I'll expand my answer tomorrow.